# C# Converting Console.Writeline outputs to String for email

Tags: c#, php, email

I have a C# Console application which outputs the data taken from mySQL however the output needs to be sent/redirected to an email via SMTP (Gmail). Is it possible to convert all the output to a string or stream like PHP which could read all the output and echo them out in the email under `messages`?

An Example of the code:

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    string datetype = (myReader["Expiry_Date"].ToString());
    DateTime dateformat = DateTime.Parse(datetype); 

    if(dateformat.Date <= calDate3b && dateformat.Date>=timenow)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Number"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Name"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Number_Yolo"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Date"].ToString());

        Console.WriteLine();                        
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Your Message");
mail.Body = <contains the console output>;
```

I have tried `StreamOutput` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
var message = new StringBuilder();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string datetype = (myReader["Expiry_Date"].ToString());
            DateTime dateformat = DateTime.Parse(datetype); 

            if(dateformat.Date <= calDate3b && dateformat.Date>=timenow)
            {
                message.AppendLine(myReader["Number"].ToString());
                message.AppendLine(myReader["Name"].ToString());
                message.AppendLine(myReader["Number_Yolo"].ToString());
                message.AppendLine(myReader["Date"].ToString());
                message.AppendLine();                    
            }
        }

Console.WriteLine(message.ToString());
mail.Body = message.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi is there a need to close the stringbuilder? Is it possible to know where it would stop reading?

Comment: When I tried to send the mail there was no contents in the email and when I tried to print out the contents of the Console.WriteLine(message.ToString()); and mail.Body there was no contents in it too.

Comment: Just got it to work. Sorry about the confusion. Didn't see the AppendLine part. Thanks!